# Specialization: PartialEq vs Rc

Tags: rust

I'd like to come up with a function that does a best-effort equality check on two values. For `T: PartialEq` it's easy, and for `Rc<T>` it's sufficient to use `Rc::ptr_eq` when `T` is not `PartialEq`.

I'm attempting to use specialization to provide the `Rc<T: !PartialEq>` case but I'm having problems with overlapping implementations, since `Rc` could implement `PartialEq`.

Is there any way to come up with a single `ref_eq` function, with or without specialization?

My code: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3c099701b3e8c5b9ac9fcdf78569f92)):

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::fmt::Display;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait RefEq {
    fn ref_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> RefEq for T {
    default fn ref_eq(&self, _other: &Self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

impl<T> RefEq for T where T: PartialEq {
    default fn ref_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self == other
    }
}

// error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `RefEq` for type `std::rc::Rc<_>`:
/*
impl<T> RefEq for Rc<T> {
    fn ref_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Rc::ptr_eq(self, other)
    }
}
*/

fn assert_ref_eq<T>() where T: RefEq { }

fn main() {
    assert_ref_eq::<f64>();             // f64 is PartialEq => ok
    assert_ref_eq::<Rc<String>>();      // String is PartialEq => ok
    assert_ref_eq::<Rc<dyn Display>>(); // dyn Display is not PartialEq =>
                                        //    please use Rc::ptr_eq
}
```